# What capability is related to TWAIN document type?

Tags: twain, twaindotnet

I am trying scan images using twain.

I see most scanner manufactures' utilities have an option called "Document Type", "Color Matching", or "Scanner Type", whatever. (Not b/w or rgb option!)

They usually let me select between `none`, `text`, `image`, and `mixed text & image` modes, as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

**Question:**

What twain capability should I use, to switch between these document types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, twain doesn't define a "Document Type" capability natively. They are defined by each manufacturers (if any).

For example, I found that some Kodak scanners use capability `0x80AC` with type `TWTY_UINT16` to define document type.

Comment: I'm using NTWAIN library in my .NET C# project. how can i send this command for EPSON and HP scanners?

Comment: @MubarakBasha I didn't find NTWAIN could send custom capability by default. You might need to modify the library yourself. I'm using my own version of twaindotnet.